# Grails : Find domain class by property

Tags: grails, groovy

I am pretty new to Grails/groovy and looking for a optimized way to write a code.

Domain class:

```
class Visitors {
    int ID;
    String destination;
    String status; // Status can be OK, FAIL, DONE, REDO, NEW, LAST, FIRST
    .........
    ..........
}
```

Now in a controller:

```
class VisitorsController {

    def getVisitors() {
        Visitors.findAllByStatus().each { } // This is where i have confusion
  }
}
```

At the commented line above, i want to get all Visitors objects that **doesn't** have **status = OK**  and then go through a loop and update there **status = REDO**.

The statuses are defined in another class:

```
public enum VisitorsStatusEnum { NEW, OK, FAIL, DONE, REDO, LAST, FIRST }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With minor modifications to enum and using [`where`](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#whereQueries) query instead of `findAllBy` would yield expected result.

```
//src/groovy
enum VisitorsStatusEnum { 
    NEW('NEW'), OK('OK'), FAIL('FAIL'), 
    DONE('DONE'), REDO('REDO'), LAST('LAST'), FIRST('FIRST')

    private final String id

    private VisitorsStatusEnum(String _value) { 
        id = _value 
    }

    String getId() { id }
}

// Domain class
class Visitors {
    Integer ID
    String destination
    VisitorsStatusEnum status
}

//Controller
class VisitorsController {
    def getVisitors() {
        def query = Visitors.where { 
            status != VisitorsStatusEnum.OK 
        }

        // Prefer batch update instead
        query.updateAll( status: VisitorsStatusEnum.REDO )

        render 'Updated'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error : Cannot query property "it" - no such property on class

Comment: Updated answer. Should be `status != VisitorsStatusEnum.OK` instead of `it.status != VisitorsStatusEnum.OK` inside where query.

Comment: Also note above implementation in the action method is an example. The implementation may vary according to your need (for example, rendering/redirecting/etc). Refer docs for more details.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. 
Is there a way to do the same using EACH as i mentioned in my original question? Because for my purpose i need an object of Visitors class and it loops through.

Comment: Yes you can. `query.list()` would give a list of visitors which is iterable. Instead of using where query, you can use dynamic finders as `Visitor.findAllByStatusNotEqual(VisitorsStatusEnum.OK)`. But where query is a `DetachedCriteria` and is lazy in operation.

Comment: For `Visitor.findAllByStatusNotEqual(VisitorsStatusEnum.OK)`, if i want to add multiple statuses, can i do something like `Visitor.findAllByStatusNotEqual(VisitorsStatusEnum.OK, VisitorsStatusEnum.NEW)`??

Comment: No. you have to use as `Visitor.findAllByStatusNotInList([VisitorStatusEnum.OK, VisitorStatusEnum.NEW])`. Refer details about usage of [`findAllBy`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html).